# Function to check whether the game has ended

Tags: c++

From looking at the below solution, can someone please tell me how can I implement a function to check whether the game has ended? I attempted this by creating "int checkEndGame" which loops through the board and returns either a 1 or 0 but it doesn't work.

Header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

int generations;
int boardWidth;
int boardHeight;

char** board;
char** boardTmp;

char deadOrAlive[] = {' ', 'x'};
char dead = deadOrAlive[0];
char alive = deadOrAlive[1];

char lookLeft(int i, int j)
{
    if ( i == 0)
    {
        return dead;
    }

    return board[i - 1][j];
}

char lookRight(int i, int j)
{
    if (i == boardWidth - 1)
    {
        return dead;
    }

    return board[i + 1][j];
}

char lookUp(int i, int j)
{
    if (j == 0)
    {
        return dead;
    }

    return board[i][j - 1];
}

char lookDown(int i, int j)
{
    if (j == boardHeight - 1)
    {
        return dead;
    }

    return board[i][j + 1];
}

char lookUpLeft(int i, int j)
{
    if (i == 0 || j == 0)
    {
        return dead;
    }

    return board[i - 1][j - 1];
}

char lookUpRight(int i, int j)
{
    if(i == boardWidth - 1 || j == 0)
    {
        return dead;
    }

    return board[i + 1][j + 1];
}

char lookDownLeft(int i, int j)
{
    if (j == boardHeight - 1 || i == 0)
    {
        return dead;
    }

    return board[i - 1][j + 1];
}

char lookDownRight(int i, int j)
{
    if (j == boardHeight - 1 || i == boardWidth - 1)
    {
        return dead;
    }

    return board[i + 1][j + 1];
}

char ans;

void init();
void setBoard();
void showBoard();
void verifyDeadOrAlive();
int getNeighbors(int i, int j);
void swap();
void sleep(unsigned int mseconds);
int checkEndGame();
void playGame();
```

c++:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "gameoflife.h"

using namespace std;

void init()
{
    cout << "How many generations would you like to cycle through? ";
    cin >> generations;

    cout << "Specify a width for the board: ";
    cin >> boardWidth;

    cout << "Specify a height for the board: ";
    cin >> boardHeight;
}

void setBoard()
{
    srand(time(0));

    board = new char*[boardWidth];
    boardTmp = new char*[boardWidth];

    for (int i = 0; i < boardWidth; ++i)
    {
        board[i] = new char[boardHeight];
        boardTmp[i] = new char[boardHeight];

        for (int j = 0; j < boardHeight; ++j)
        {
            board[i][j] = deadOrAlive[rand() % generations];
            boardTmp[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

void showBoard()
{
    system("cls");

    for (int j = 0; j < boardHeight; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < boardWidth; ++i)
        {
            cout << board[i][j];
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void verifyDeadOrAlive()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < boardHeight; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < boardWidth; ++i)
        {
            int neighbors = getNeighbors(i, j);

            if (board[i][j] == alive)
            {
                if (neighbors < 2 || neighbors > 3)
                {
                    boardTmp[i][j] = dead;
                }
                else
                {
                    boardTmp[i][j] = alive;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (neighbors == 3)
                {
                    boardTmp[i][j] = alive;
                }
                else
                {
                    boardTmp[i][j] = dead;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    swap();
}

int getNeighbors(int i, int j)
{
    int x = 0;

    if (lookLeft(i, j) == alive)
    {
        x++;
    }
    if (lookRight(i, j) == alive)
    {
        x++;
    }
    if (lookUp(i, j) == alive)
    {
        x++;
    }
    if (lookDown(i, j) == alive)
    {
        x++;
    }
    if (lookUpLeft(i, j) == alive)
    {
        x++;
    }
    if (lookUpRight(i, j) == alive)
    {
        x++;
    }
    if (lookDownLeft(i, j) == alive)
    {
        x++;
    }
    if (lookDownRight(i, j) == alive)
    {
        x++;
    }

    return x;
}

void swap()
{
    char** tmp = board;
    board = boardTmp;
    boardTmp = tmp;
}

void sleep(unsigned int mseconds)
{
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
    while (goal > clock());
}

int checkEndGame()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < boardHeight; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < boardWidth; ++i)
        {
            if (board[i][j] == dead)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

void playGame()
{
    init();

    setBoard();

    do
    {
        showBoard();

        sleep(500);

        verifyDeadOrAlive();

        checkEndGame();
    }
    while (checkEndGame == 0);
}

int main()
{
    do
    {
        playGame();

        cout << "Would you like to play again? y/n: ";
        cin >> ans;

        system("cls");
    }
    while (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a helpful problem description. What *precisely* did you expect? What *precisely* actually happened?

Comment: would help to know what defines your game as "over"..

Comment: What does the function `swap` do? Its called in `verifyDeadOrAlive`. Are there threads created anywhere at all?

Comment: Technically, Conway's Game of Life is a simulation that *has no end* until the user tells it to stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this:

```
int checkEndGame()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < boardHeight; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < boardWidth; ++i)
        {
            if (board[i][j] == alive)
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Your function returns the moment it sees one *dead* cell, which is incorrect. You can abort if you see one live cell. But otherwise, you need to check every cell.

Also:

```
        checkEndGame();
    }
    while (checkEndGame == 0);
```

is broken. `checkEndGame` will never be zero since it's a pointer to a function. You want:

```
}
while (checkEndGame() == 0);
```

Comment: +1 because you've got it right, but you could do more and explain why this works and why the OP's solution is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

a
You function should be like that:

```
int checkEndGame()
 {
 for (int j = 0; j < boardHeight; ++j)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < boardWidth; ++i)
    {
        if (board[i][j] == alive){return 0; }
    }
  }

 return 1;
}
```

Because you either find "alive" and say game is not over yet, or have to go through the hole board and then say the game is over because you haven't found "alive".

And as said before:

```
while(checkEndGame==0)
```

doesn't run the function to see what the returned value is, done this way all it does is checking if the memory address of you function is 0 (which it will most certainly never be unless you assign it).

to run the function and see the returned value you have to write:

```
while(checkEndGame()==0)
```

(notice the "()" at the end)